# Set custom order status - Dependant on delivery method

Tags: shipping-methods, order-status, delivery

I am wondering how I can set a order status that is driven by the delivery method chosen by a customer.

Currently I am using magentos "Free Delivery" option which I have labelled as "Collect In Store".

If someone uses this delivery option and pays for an item the order is set to "Complete". What I want is for the order to be set to "Ready for Collection" until someone manually sets it to complete once a customer has collected it.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Create [custom order status](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/order-processing/order-status-custom.html).

You can use the `sales_order_payment_pay` event to set the order status after payment is completed successfully.
[sales_order_payment_pay](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84106/45103)

Or if you want to set status after invoice generation then you can use `sales_order_invoice_save_after`, this is triggered when an invoice is made so you are sure the order is paid as well.
[sales_order_invoice_save_after](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9029/45103)

Then [change status](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79309/45103) in observer.